# rails mvc helper class for calling outside data (Viddler)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model-view-controller, model, controller

I've got an app that is using Viddler's API and the viddler-ruby gem. Originally there was only one spot in the app that was going to authenticate and request video information, but there's been a change and I might need to do it in a few places.

I could do it as a method in `application_helper` but then whenever that method would be called it would authenticate and perform a function (and as I'm thinking about it, there could be more than one function needed).

So I'm thinking a class upon instantiation, authenticates, keeps that authenticated @viddler object and has public methods that can be called on the class (ie ViddlerMaster.getImage(video)) -- my question is is this a controller or a model? In my thinking it's dealing with data so it'll be a model, one that doesn't connect to the database in any way; is my thinking correct, or is there A Better Way?

Comment: It's not a model or controller, it's just a library/utility class.

Comment: Even though it is technically connecting to data though not ActiveRecord?

Comment: Almost everything uses data in *some* form. It's not a model unless it... models. A service might *use* a non-persisted model to *store* data it retrieves (and probably should), but "the data" and "how you get the data" are two separate concepts, although they might conceivably live in the same module if it's tightly coupled.